# How to detect Azure Storage type using SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I need to be able to detect the type of storage that a certain account offers. For example, if a user gives me their Storage Account and Key, I need to be able to detect whether or not it is a Premium LRS type of storage. I have looked at the CloudStorageAccount class without any luck. Does anyone know how I can detect this programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Azure Management API's for this.  Initialize StorageManagementClient object and "Get" a storage account from it.
storageAccount.Properties.AccountType contains if the account is "Premium" or other

Storage Nuget package for Management API is: [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage/) (classic) or [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage/5.0.1-preview) (v2/ARM)